# How to use a string in a variable as a Perl array reference

Tags: perl

I am trying to run a loop on the strings in the `$ACES_1_key` but I get `Can't use string ... as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use`.

```
my $ACES_1_key = ("`NIL-RETURN`,`ASSESSEE-NAME`,`LTU`,`MONTH`,`RETURN-YEAR`,`REGISTRATION-NUMBER`");

foreach my $key (@$ACES_1_key) {
  print $key;
}
```

Comment: Well, your `$ACES_1_key` simply *isn't* an arrayref, therefore it *can't* be used as one, much like I cannot use a bicycle as an airplane. Do you want to parse that string into an array? This won't happen automatically. Either do it with regexes, or use the Text::CSV parser.

Comment: Are the backticks part of the array elements, or just an attempt to use as a quote character?

Comment: You seem to be confused and probably need to read a bit about arrays and hashes.  Even about variables, I guess (referring to `my $ACES_1_key`).

Comment: @SlavenRezic,@devnull i am inserting the data into MYSQL from XML and the values in $ACES_1_key are the column headers as they have hyphen so i have included backticks....i wanted to check if column exists hence was trying to run the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using capital letters in lexical variable names. They are reserved for global identifiers such as package names.

If you are trying to *set up* an array reference in the first place then you want something like this:

```
my $aces_1_key = [ qw[ NIL-RETURN ASSESSEE-NAME LTU MONTH RETURN-YEAR REGISTRATION-NUMBER ] ];

foreach my $key (@$aces_1_key) {
  print $key, "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
NIL-RETURN
ASSESSEE-NAME
LTU
MONTH
RETURN-YEAR
REGISTRATION-NUMBER
```

Alternatively, if you have a string that you need to split into individual substrings then there are a few ways to. The program below shows one. It splits the string at the commas to produce a list of quoted substrings. Then the quotes are removed inside the loop using `tr//`. The output is identical to that of the previous example.

```
my $aces_1_key=("`NIL-RETURN`,`ASSESSEE-NAME`,`LTU`,`MONTH`,`RETURN-YEAR`,`REGISTRATION-NUMBER`");

foreach my $key (split /,/, $aces_1_key) {
  $key =~ tr/`//d;
  print $key, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my @ACES_1_key = (
    'NIL-RETURN',
    'ASSESSEE-NAME',
    'LTU',
    'MONTH',
    'RETURN-YEAR',
    'REGISTRATION-NUMBER'
);
foreach my $key (@ACES_1_key) {
    print $key;
}
```

(I requoted the elements and made the variable an actual array)

(and didn't test it)

Comment: can i have backticks in array as i am using these as MYSQL column names as these are having hyphen and it's needed to add backtick to run a query.

Comment: You can have backticks as long as you put them *inside* the regular single quotes.